# 18.04. Can only sign-in via wayland which appears not to support Nvidia GPU needed for extra Displaylink monitor

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, login, multiple-monitors, wayland

NOTE! I am principally a 'user' with some technical knowledge rather than someone who uses the CLI most of the time.

I upgraded from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS as I read that 18.04 fully supported Displaylink USB 2.0. My laptop has integrated Intel GPU and discrete Nvidia GPU. After boot I see 'UBUNTU' and underlining dots on all 3 monitors (laptop, external & Displaylink). Then the sign-in appears and the Displaylink monitor no longer has a signal. I assumed I needed to use the Nvidia GPU to support 3 screens.

I read that Nvidia does not work with Wayland so I tried both the other options available via the sign-in cog - Ubuntu & Ubuntu via Unity - the sign-in page goes away and comes back again moments later. I can only sign-in via Wayland

Checked 'details' graphics=Intel® Sandybridge Mobile.

Checked 'additional drivers'=using nvidia-driver-390 (recommended).

$prime-select query shows 'nvidia'.

Research says edit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and remove the comment from    #WaylandEnable=false but this caused initialisation of GDM to hang.

Lots of hits on similar questions but no 'simple' solutions work for me and other solutions are rather too technical for me to attempt as I do not fully understand them.